# Python: How do I compare one element of a list with every other elements besides itself?

Tags: python

For example, `listA = [1,2,3,4,5]`, and I want to multiply each element with `listA[4]` and get maximum product without `listA[4] * listA[4]`

Comment: You can use [pop()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop) to pull the element out of the list and use it, just be aware that you should copy the list before popping, as it acts in-place. Beyond that, please post code for what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi @Cup, this sounds like a homework exercise to me. Can you show the code that you wrote?

Comment: @G.Anderson I am thinking about using pop(), and then for loop to iterate each elements * listA[4], and append() to a new list, and then get the maximum from there

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy here

```
import numpy as np
listA = [1,2,3,4,5]
num=4
to_multiply = listA.pop(num)
listA=np.array(listA)
max(listA*to_multiply)
```

Or
slice the numpy array without popping any element

```
import numpy as np
listA = [1,2,3,4,5]
num=4
listA= np.array(listA)
max(listA[range(0,num)+range(num+1,len(listA))]*listA[num])
```

Or

```
max([listA[i]*listA[num] for i in range(0,len(listA)) if i!=num])
```

Or

```
listA = [1,2,3,4,5]
num=4
to_multiply = listA.pop(num)
max([(i*j) for i,j in zip(listA,[to_multiply]*num)])
```

Comment: is there a way to do it using only for loop and list method

Answer (score 0):

its also possible without numpy using list comprehension

```
max([a*listA[4] for i,a in enumerate(listA]) if i!=4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a readable iteration approach. Compute max among all indices except the target index:

```
listA = [1,2,3,4,5]

TARGET_INDEX = 4
maximum = 0
for i, val in enumerate(listA):
    if i == TARGET_INDEX:
        continue

    maximum = max(maximum, val*listA[TARGET_INDEX])

print maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5]

maxN = 0
otherElement = 0
elementToMult = 4
for i, n in enumerate(someList):
  tempVar = n * someList[elementToMult]
  print(n, i, tempVar)
  if tempVar > maxN:
    maxN = tempVar
    otherElement = i

print("The max is {0} which is {1} * {2}".format(maxN,someList[otherElement], someList[elementToMult]))
```

This will give you the maximum product & the element to multiply with the given element to get the max product

Answer (score 0):

This can either achieved with `heapq.nlargest()`

```
import heapq as q

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(q.nlargest(2,[x*a[4] for x in a][1:]))
```

OR simple `sorted()`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(sorted([x*a[4] for x in a])[(len(a)-2):(len(a)-1)])
```

Even shorter with `enumerate()`:

```
import heapq as q

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(q.nlargest(1,[x*a[4] for i, x in enumerate(a) if i != 4]))
```

OR simple `max()` + enumerate():

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(max([x*a[4] for i, x in enumerate(a) if i != 4]))
```

**NOTE:** heqpq ones return list.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing one element with all other elements except itself. Given that all element in an array are positive int, i took maxP as -1, you can set a different value according to the listA given range.

```
maxP = -1
for i in range(len(listA)):
        for j in range(i,len(listA)):
       
            if i!=j:
              prod = listA[i] * listA[j]
              if prod > maxP:
                 maxP = prod
return maxP
```

Comment: Please consider editing your description of your solution.  It's a bit hard to understand.